# How to enable syntax highlighting in ediff?

Tags: emacs

I'm using ediff to review patches (via magit-ediff). It works well, but I would like to have syntax highlighting during the patch review (i.e. just like [github does](https://github.com/blog/1932-syntax-highlighted-diffs)).
Is that possible?
If not, what would be the best way of achieving that goal?

Comment: If you call ediff on buffers which are syntax-highlighted, they don't *lose* their syntax-highlighting (although obviously any ediff faces with an explicit foreground colour will have that effect while active; YMMV for disabling those, depending on how well the original foregrounds contrast with the ediff backgrounds...)

Comment: @Thomas Do you mean background highlighting rather than syntax highlighting?

Comment: I mean having the background following the diff highlight (usually red / green for removed / added lines), and the foreground following the code syntax highlight.

@phils interesting. I will check if my theme doesn't mess up with background colors.